# Why is a nameserver address not removed from resolv.conf when disconnecting from my work network?

Tags: network-manager, resolv.conf, dnsmasq

Using networkmanager and dnsmasq.

When I'm at work I have a wifi connection that is statically configured with IP, dns server, and domain search.

When I connect, `resolv.conf` has both the server and the domain search, along with the `dnsmasq` entry of 127.0.1.1.

When I go home and get on my dhcp wifi connection, the domain search is removed from `resolv.conf`, but the work dns server isn't removed. As a result all my browsing drags. I can manually remove the entry, but when `resolv.conf` gets rebuilt it's back in there again (I expect that).

I think the real problem is that when NM connects to the work wifi it should hand the dns server to dnsmasq, not put it in resolv.conf, as a result when I disconnect it doesn't take it out.

Comment: Can you check in your /etc/dnsmasq.conf if the entry "no-resolv" is set?

Comment: `root@rplp2:/etc# cat /etc/dnsmasq.conf
cat: /etc/dnsmasq.conf: No such file or directory`

Comment: Where did you enter the work nameserver address? Give the exact filename(s) or field name(s) in the NetworkManager  configuration editor where the address has been entered . Also, please post the output of the /usr/share/resolvconf/dump-debug-info utility, run in a terminal window. This utility script can be found in the latest resolvconf packages in Debian and Ubuntu. Failing that, at least post the output of the command `ls -l /run/resolvconf/interface`.

Comment: I'm using the gui, /usr/bin/nm-connection-editor

Answer (score 0):

You write: «When I connect, resolv.conf has both the server and the domain search, along with the dnsmasq entry of 127.0.1.1.»

This is improper behavior.

NetworkManager should give the nameserver address(es) to dnsmasq and *not* submit them to the resolvconf utility (which manages resolv.conf) and/or write them directly into /etc/resolv.conf.

NetworkManager itself in Ubuntu behaves correctly, at least under default/normal circumstances.

Are you using a NetworkManager extention or third-party utility program to configure a VPN or something of that nature? There may be a bug in that extention or utility such that the software sends the work nameserver address statement to resolvconf and doesn't remove it when you leave work.

Third-party software is often not properly integrated with Ubuntu, and in particular often fails to use resolvconf to add and remove nameserver information.  Read /usr/share/doc/resolvconf/README.gz for information about resolvconf.

Comment: I'm not using any third party utility or extensions.